# plotting multiple column from excel with matplotlib

Tags: python, excel, numpy, matplotlib

I have data which looks like :

```
sites   mp1     mp2
ry99    0.66    0.54
ry98    0.71    0.54
ry97    0.58    0.45
ry96    0.65    0.55
```

I have the list below in an excel file and I would like to plot the second and third column against the first one, all in the same graph using matplotlib.

When I tried the following code, I receive an error :

```
plt.plot (arr[1:,0],arr[1:,n],label=names[n])
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

This is my code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
arr = np.genfromtxt('C:\\Users\\abdulaziz.bello\\Desktop\\geodesy\\es99.csv', delimiter=' ', dtype=None) 
names = (arr[0]) 
for n in range (1,len(names)): 
    plt.plot (arr[1:,0],arr[1:,n],label=names[n]) 
plt.legend()    
plt.show()
```

Any help will be highly appreciated to solve my problem. I'm beginning with Python

Comment: Since you are reading a .csv file, you should probably use `delimiter=','`.  That may fix your problem, but its hard to know unless you post the data too.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code which should solve your problem :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


arr = np.genfromtxt('file', delimiter='   ', dtype=None, names =['sites','mp1','mp2'], skip_header=1)

x = np.arange(4)

plt.xticks(x, arr['sites'])

plt.plot(x, arr['mp1'])
plt.plot(x, arr['mp2'])

plt.show()
```

The result is :

[image]

Comment: I tried the solution suggested but go the same error